# Java URL Exception from read file with java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, file

```
public class tset {
     public static void main(String[] args){
            try{

                File file = new File("url_file.txt");
                FileReader filereader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(filereader);
                String line = "";
                String input = "";

                while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null){
                    String url = line;
                    String url2 =  "\""+line+"\"";
                    URL url3 = new URL(line);
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();
                    Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
                    for (Element p : paragraphs)
                        input += p;
                }

                bufReader.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e);
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
}
```

url_file.txt contains https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing.

I've done a search on stackoverflow to solve this problem
We could not find an answer other than to add https: //.
(http: //, https: // will all get the same error)

In addition, I tried new URL or Jsoup.connect and use like url2 but all failed.

I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Was the text file created by Notepad?  I suspect a byte order mark is the first character in the file.  Try printing `(int) line.charAt(0)`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
 at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693) what is this mean? what i shoud create text file??

Comment: It means you have a string of length zero.  This is caused by reading a blank line.  You will need to add some code to check for blank lines, since obviously an empty string is not a valid URL.

Comment: isn't it checked from line = bufReader.readLine()) != null in while loop?

Comment: No.  A string with zero length is an object;  `null` is not an object.

Comment: oh my god... i add blank line first line it's sovled i don't know why this happen Thank you very much VGR!!